# .htaccess rules doesn't work for .php files but for .html works

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

My very simple .htaccess rules doesn't work for .php files but for .html works fine.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^about$ about.html [NC]
```

This one correct display about.html when i user /about

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php [NC]
```

This doesn't work. Do you have any idea?
Ubuntu 16 server with apache2

And one more, when i remove

```
RewriteRule ^about$ about.html [NC]
```

from first options redirection still works...

My conf looks like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

When i remove Directory from config file the redirection stop working.

Comment: "And one more, when i remove ... from first options redirection still works" so basically your htaccess has no effect?

Comment: yes, you're right. When i create about1.html redirection /about1 works without any change in .htaccess

Comment: Then you've got some other redirect or rewrite code somewhere - that isn't something that happens automatically in Apache

Comment: It is brand new Ubuntu. When I remove my .htaccess redirection still works. Is there any other mechanism that is responsible for it?

Comment: Browsers keep redirections in cache, which is kind of annoying when debugging them. If you're using Chrome, you can click and hold the refresh button while the developper tools are opened and you will be offered 3 choices. "Empty cache and hard reload" usually does it for me.

Comment: hmmm, so why about1 works even if there was no mention of him in .htaccess but thanks i'll check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

When I removed almost everything, it worked correctly. Maybe someday this help someone. Thanks for Your time.